# Подключение http client Apache

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, httpclient

Здравствуйте! Решил поработать с vk api, впрочем, через браузерную строку все просто превосходно :) Решил перенести работу на свою любимую Java и возник вопрос: как эмулировать запрос через браузер? Нашел ответ - http client Apache. Так вот установить я его не смог, потому как ответа в гуголе нет (во всяком случае нормального я не видел, а только ссылки на скачку). Есть замечательный человек, который расписал с ним подробно работу, но не рассказал, как подключить этот клиент, собственно, [вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144813/). Ну и отсюда просьба (вопрос) - как установить этот клиент? Или если кто может - опишите этот процесс.
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если используете maven для сборки проекта, то добавьте в pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.5.2</version>
```

если через ant, то скачайте .jar файл и в ide пропишите путь к библиотеке.

Comment: Благодарю  за ответ